# What is going on here? The formula is correct but the answer isn't

Tags: java, math, intellij-idea

```
public static double Fraction2Decimal(int Numerator, int Denominator)
{
    double Answer = Numerator / Denominator;
    return Answer;
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    double ans = Fraction2Decimal(2, 8);

    double pi = 3.141592653589793238462643383;
    System.out.print(ans);
}
```

What this code is doing is converting fractions to a decimal/double, 2/8 as a decimal is 0.25 as everyone knows but IntelliJ IDE returns this

```
0.0
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Huh! its should return 0.25, could anyone explain what is going on here?

EDIT:
I only did by just to check that the type was to short for the answer.

Comment: 2/8 is 0. That's how int division works.

Comment: integer division. Google it

Comment: "everyone knows" - check your assumptions and read about integer division.

Comment: If everyone knows it anyway, you don't need to write software to calculate it. :)

Comment: Thanks, just changed the int's to float and it returned the right answer `0.25`, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score -1):

Because you are dividing to ints, that can only produce an int. And on division, they get floored (rounded to the lower integer).
Try casting them to double o float before doing the operation.

Comment: Please don't answer to logical error, and evident duplicate